# Hide and Un-hide div elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

i have two DIV named[DIV1,DIv2] inside my page , where i can hide and un-hide each one of them, now is it possible when page will load automatically DIV1 will show then Div2 will hide and when you click the button to show DIV2 then automatically DIV1 will hide.  i have provided example below..

```js
function myFunction1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
#myDIV1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#myDIV2 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>



<button onclick="myFunction1()">Div1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Div2</button>

<div id="myDIV1">
This is First Div.
</div>

<div id="myDIV2">
This is Second Div.
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: only one of the div must show something like if div1 is click div2 is hide then if div2 is click div1 is hide

Comment: on page load, you want to show only one div? which div? how to make autohide the second div when i click the first div? - @Grace which will make both the div to hide. is that is what you looking?

Comment: div1 will show on page load then when i click the div 2 button automaticaly div1 will hide, right now both will show i need to click back again then each button to hide one of them,

Comment: @Gracw can you check my answer? is this is what you looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal approach would be to create a class (`hidden` as in the example below) which hides a particular element. Assign this class initially to second div so that it doesn't appear when page loads.

Then you can add/remove this class on particular elements when the function runs, as desired.

See the demo below:

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
  var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
  x.classList.remove('hidden');
  y.classList.add('hidden');
}

function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
  var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
  y.classList.remove('hidden');
  x.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

```css
#myDIV1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#myDIV2 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Div1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Div2</button>

<div id="myDIV1">
  This is First Div.
</div>

<div id="myDIV2" class="hidden">
  This is Second Div.
</div>
```

Comment: thank you sir, this looks cool also , if im going to add more dive i just copy the code back?

Comment: @Grace -- Yes. The ideal practice to do such things is to use CSS classes. This encourages better code management.

Answer (score 2):

Now at least one `div` will be there on the screen.

```js
   

  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
  var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
 function myFunction1() {
  x.style.display = "block";
  y.style.display = "none";
}

function myFunction2() {
  y.style.display = "block";
  x.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myDIV1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#myDIV2 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>



<button onclick="myFunction1()">Div1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Div2</button>

<div id="myDIV1">
This is First Div.
</div>

<div id="myDIV2">
This is Second Div.
</div>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      #myDIV1 {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 50px 0;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: blue;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      #myDIV2 {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 50px 0;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: red;
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: none;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="toggleDisplay()">Div1</button>
    <button onclick="toggleDisplay()">Div2</button>

    <div id="myDIV1">
      This is First Div.
    </div>
    <div id="myDIV2">
      This is Second Div.
    </div>

    <script>
      function toggleDisplay() {
        var div1 = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
        var div2 = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
        if (div1.style.display === "none") {
          div1.style.display = "block";
          div2.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          div1.style.display = "none";
          div2.style.display = "block";
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

you can have one function to handle this though :-)
toggling block and none for display css

Comment: Sir thank you this is perfect got it correctly, just follow up question if i'm going to add more divs the JavaScript ill just edit the else statement?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap4 then there is already 'd-none' class. you can use that. check below snippet.

```js
function myFunction1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
    var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
    
    x.classList.remove("d-none");
    y.classList.add("d-none");
    
    
}

function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV1");
    var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
    
    y.classList.remove("d-none");
    x.classList.add("d-none");
}
```

```css
#myDIV1 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#myDIV2 {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<button onclick="myFunction1()">Div1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Div2</button>

<div id="myDIV1">
This is First Div.
</div>

<div class="d-none" id="myDIV2">
This is Second Div.
</div>





</body>
</html>
```